# C# Razor Get variable

Tags: c#, razor

I'm currently working with C# and I want to get the variable of a GET method. (like this: index.cshtml?id=thisvariable)

I'm currently using:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
```

And it works, but I don't know how to get the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get data sent by a `GET` request, you read the `QueryString` from the `Request`.

```
var id = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"];
```

You should also add checks to make sure that the `QueryString[KEY]` exists, so that you don't get a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to find a `KEY` that is not present.